# get current user id laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get the id of the current user on my controller this way

```
$post->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
```

I'm importing these classes

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use conocermusica\Post;
use Illuminate\Support\Fecades\Redirect;
use conocermusica\Http\Requests\PostFormRequest;
use DB;
```

when I add:

```
use Auth;
```

I get the error

> (1/1) FatalThrowableError Class 'Illuminate\Support\Fecades\Redirect'
>   not found

How can I resolve this?

Comment: It is not `Fecades` it is `Facades`, with `a`

Comment: Can be closed as fixed by typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your import is wrong:

The path is `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
```

**OR**

```
use Redirect;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the others said you path is misspelled.
It should be :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
```

Also you have a shorter way to get the user id with `Auth::id()` instead of `Auth::user()->id`